# Using a headset with Rock Band 3 for vocals

Tags: xbox-360, rock-band-3

In the past, I've played guitar in RB3/GHWT and sung at the same time using a mic stand and the GHWT mic. This works fine with the stock mic, because the guitar's strum and buttons are fairly quiet. However, I like playing drums more, but they don't play nicely with the mic because of their being considerably louder... Thus, I was wondering if it would be possible to use a gaming headset instead of the speakers and stock mic; listening through the headphones and singing through the mic. Could this work? Has anyone tried it? I was considering using a standard USB headset, but they use the same plug for mic and audio out, which wouldn't work. Thus, I'm thinking about using a standard 3.5mm headset with separate stereo plugs for mic and headphones, with the mic plug attached to my 360 via a 3.5mm -> USB converter of sorts (see below). Thoughts?

Something like these:

- [http://www.amazon.com/Channel-External-Sound-Audio-Adapter/dp/B007HISGRW/ref=pd_sim_e_4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007HISGRW)
- [http://www.amazon.com/Syba-SD-CM-UAUD-Adapter-C-Media-Chipset/dp/B001MSS6CS/ref=pd_sim_e_1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001MSS6CS)

TL;DR: Can I use a gaming headset's mic for vocals in Rock Band 3 (Xbox 360)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, this is possible.**  I currently own the ion Drumset and the Turtle Beach PX21 headset.   I have played drums and sang at the same time ( it's rather difficult!).

Just don't expect to play drums and be in a voice chat party at the same time because if you don't talk, the headset will start to pick up the sound of the Drumset. (Though, during my gameplay, the mic picking up the drum noises doesn't really seem to matter when I am singing).    I would recommend getting some sort of silencers for your Drumset to muffle the noise.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I usually play solo or local anyways (my XBL Gold expired), and I only really sing along when I'm playing casually (read as: a difficulty lower than I should be at).